# ajax validator callout extender position issue within modal popup - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Within the modal pop up , ajax validator callout extender not showing near to the Text box position.

I find out the reason for this issue. This problem occur only when scroll occur in modal pop up window.

If not scroll occur in modal pop up window means, ajax validator callout extender shows correctly in proper position.

how to fix this issue.

thanks in advance. .

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1240131.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to display a modal dialog with callout extender validation. What a pain!!!

- First you have to use an `UpdatePanel`.
- Then `ContentTemplate`, `aspPanel` (or div), table, other controls etc...
- now this is the important part. The Validators have to be INSIDE the Panel ( which is inside the UpdatePanel.)
- Also, `ModalPopupExtender` must be INSIDE the UpdatePanel (i.e. inside the ContentTemplate tag.)
- Other fine points.

  - poperties of UpdatePanel : `UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false"`
  - On Panel `ScrollBars="None"`
- and one last strange annomaly (sp?), I had to set the `TargetControlID="hdnStepByStepButton"` which is
  a hidden button wit `CausesValidation="False"`. This has something to do with the fact that the button I wanted to use was in a UserControl which was not available to me.
- And last but not least, if you have multiple validators, you will want to set the `ValidationGroup="myGroup"` for the button and all of the other controls to be validated.

hope this helps!

good luck! and this is just another reason to switch to Silverlight!!